# ¿Como usar array.push para agregar elemento a un array?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera agregar a mi primer elemento del array al campo ayer un valor con array.push, no se muy bien como sea la estructura para poder agregar este valor.
intente de la siguiente forma

```
var cumpleaños = [
  {
    ayer: "",
  },
  {
    hoy: "12-07-20",
}  ,
  {
    mañana: "12-08-20"
}
];
cumpleaños.push([0].ayer.("12-06-20"))
console.log(cumpleaños[0].ayer)
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var cumpleaños = [
  {
    ayer: "",
  },
  {
    hoy: "12-07-20",
}  ,
  {
    mañana: "12-08-20"
}
];
// Simplemente accede al primer elemento del array ([0]) y directamente modifica su atributo fecha
cumpleaños[0].ayer = "12-06-20";
console.log(cumpleaños[0].ayer)
```

[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) sirve para AÑADIR nuevos valores a un ARRAY, el objeto que se encuentra en el primer puesto del array, no es un array, el `push()` te serviría por ejemplo para añadir `{anteayer:""}` a tu array de cumpleaños, pero no para editarlo, para eso simplemente tienes que acceder al valor que quieres modificar tal como te muestro en el código de arriba.